# Add a slider in a shape divider with Bootstrap 4

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap 4, and I would like to insert an image slider in the red shape (by keeping the shape divider).

Is it possible ?

https://jsfiddle.net/q5rk9zj7/

```css
.custom-shape-divider-bottom-1641841276 {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    line-height: 0;
}

.custom-shape-divider-bottom-1641841276 svg {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: calc(300% + 1.3px);
    height: 255px;
    background: red;
}

.custom-shape-divider-bottom-1641841276 .shape-fill {
    fill: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="custom-shape-divider-bottom-1641841276">
    <svg data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1200 120" preserveAspectRatio="none">
        <path d="M600,112.77C268.63,112.77,0,65.52,0,7.23V120H1200V7.23C1200,65.52,931.37,112.77,600,112.77Z" class="shape-fill"></path>
    </svg>
    <h1>SLIDER</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to write html code inside th svg code and managed by the css whatever you want

```
<div class="custom-shape-divider-bottom-1641841276">
    <svg data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1200 120" preserveAspectRatio="none">
        <path d="M600,112.77C268.63,112.77,0,65.52,0,7.23V120H1200V7.23C1200,65.52,931.37,112.77,600,112.77Z" class="shape-fill">
          <img />
          <h1>SLIDER</h1>
        </path>
    </svg>  
</div>
```